# Java Array Bound Exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program for a password security, but many times I get Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception...I tried to fix, but nothing, this is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BruteForce {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String password = "aaaa";
        char[] charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        BruteForce bf = new BruteForce(charset, 1);

        String attempt = bf.toString();
        while (true) {
            if (attempt.equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("Password Found: " + attempt); // low security
                break;
            }
            attempt = bf.toString();
            System.out.println(attempt);
            bf.increment();
        }
    }

    private char[] cs;
    private char[] cg;

    public BruteForce(char[] characterSet, int guessLength) {
        cs = characterSet;
        cg = new char[guessLength];
        Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
    }

    public void increment() {
        int index = cg.length - 1;
        while (index >= 0) {
            if (cg[index] == cs[cs.length - 1]) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    cg = new char[cg.length + 1];
                    Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
                    break;
                } else {
                    cg[index] = cs[0];
                    index--;
                }
            } else {
                cg[index] = cs[Arrays.binarySearch(cs, cg[index]) + 1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(cg);
    }
}
```

When I try to add special char(s):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BruteForce 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

String password = "aaaa";
char[] charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.@#".toCharArray();
BruteForce bf = new BruteForce(charset, 1);

String attempt = bf.toString();
while (true) 
{
if (attempt.equals(password)) 
{
System.out.println("Password Found: " + attempt); // low security
break;
}
attempt = bf.toString();
System.out.println(attempt);
bf.increment();
}
}
private char[] cs;
private char[] cg;

public BruteForce(char[] characterSet, int guessLength) 
{
cs = characterSet;
cg = new char[guessLength];
Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
}

public void increment() 
{
int index = cg.length - 1;
while(index >= 0) 
{
if (cg[index] == cs[cs.length-1]) 
{
if (index == 0) 
{
cg = new char[cg.length+1];
Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
break;
}
else 
{
cg[index] = cs[0];
index--;
}
} 
else 
{
cg[index] = cs[Arrays.binarySearch(cs, cg[index]) + 1];
break;
}
}
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
return String.valueOf(cg);
}
}
```

And I get something like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -65

Comment: Can you please provide your error log ??

Comment: Which line does the Exception point to?

Comment: I just ran your program. It found `"aaaa"`. No exception was thrown.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Right this program is not throwing any exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -14
at BruteForce.increment(BruteForce.java:56) at BruteForce.main(BruteForce.java:22)...this when I try to add special chars

Comment: Guys, OP has already told **but many times I get Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception** .. This is erratic .. If somebody down voted just because they didn't get any exception, then it is bad ..

Comment: Which password are you trying to BruteForce?

Comment: @DavidJacke You need to show us the code for `when I try to add special chars`. Without the actual code you're using it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between

```
"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

and

```
"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.@#"
```

is that in the first case, the characters are in ascending order (characters in java have a value).

`Arrays.binarySearch` requires the array to be in ascending order.

If you use

```
"#.0123456789@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

instead (or use `Arrays.sort` in the `BruteForce` constructor) it should work.

Always remember to post the **exact** code that you are using!

Comment: ok, but I add these special characters in run-time, for example: `combination += ".#@";`. How can I sort it in ascending order?

Comment: @DavidJacke Whenever you change `combination` you have to do `cs = combination.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(cs);`. This should be a method of `BruteForce`.

Comment: ok, it should go now. just do `Arrays.sort(charset);`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DavidJacke Not a problem. Glad I could help!